# What is this extra row in the UITabBar (Swift)

Tags: swift, tabbar

I programmatically add a TableView in a ViewController, then appeared an extra row. I would like to be able to manage it, but first I would have to know what it is. This line seems to come from the TabBar rather than the TableView. Do you know which object it is?

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPA4m.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPA4m.jpg)]

The code:

```
import UIKit

final class SearchViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    private let ingredients = [
        "flour",
        "sugar",
        "eggs",
        "butter",
        "baking powder",
        "vanilla extract",
        "milk",
        "salt",
        "cocoa powder",
        "yeast",
        "olive oil",
        "cheese",
        "breadcrumbs",
        "onions",
        "garlic",
        "tomatoes",
        "basil",
        "oregano",
        "thyme",
        "parsley",
        "pepper"
    ]

    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let ingredient = ingredients[indexPath.row]
        var cellConfig = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        cellConfig.text = ingredient
        cell.contentConfiguration = cellConfig
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        ingredients.count
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let header = StretchyTableHeaderView(
            frame: CGRect(
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: view.frame.size.width,
                height: view.frame.size.width / 2
            )
        )

        view.addSubview(tableView)
        header.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "header")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        tableView.tableHeaderView = header
    }
}

extension SearchViewController2: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard let header = tableView.tableHeaderView as? StretchyTableHeaderView else { return }
        header.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: tableView)
    }
}
```

I tried to add/remove a footer in the TableView... No changes.

Comment: Try to see with Debug View Hierarchy button of XCode what it is. Also, when you do `tableView.frame = view.bounds`, it might be premature, because the `view.bounds` isn't correct yet (layout hasn't been made)

Comment: OK, thanks! In my case it's a UIButtonBarStackView